# How to find all longest common subsequences of multiple sequences?

Tags: r

I am trying to find all longest subsequences common to multiple sequences.

I have tried [LCS](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/qualV/versions/0.3-3/topics/LCS) function from qualV package, but it only worked for two sequences and returned only one of the longest subsequences when multiple resulting subsequences exist.

**Example Input**

```
list(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), 
     c(5, 1, 2, 4, 3), 
     c(1, 2, 5, 3, 4), 
     c(5, 1, 2, 3, 4))
```

**Expected Output**

```
[[1]]
[1] 1 2 3

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 4
```

*update:

I have confused people with the word *subsequence*, so I would like to define the word *subsequence* **specifically** to this question.

***a subsequence of a sequence must contain only the elements of the sequence and be in the order of the sequence***

for example, c(5, 1, 4) is a subsequence of c(5, 1, 2, 4, 3), but c(5, 4, 1) is NOT a subsequence of c(5, 1, 2, 4, 3)

Comment: Isn't this similar to [your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55149436/how-to-find-longest-common-increasing-subsequence-of-multiple-numeric-vectors) ?

Comment: @markus it is similar, but without the increasing requirement, I think such requirement is confusing and unnecessary

Comment: Not clear to me. Why is `1 2 4` and `1 2 5` is missing?

Comment: @Sotos `1 2 4` is not missing; `1 2 5` is missing because `c(5, 1, 2, 3, 4)` doesn't contain `1 2 5` as a subsequence

Comment: Neither `1 2 4`. I must be missing something

Comment: @Sotos **Expected Output** `[[2]]` `[1] 1 2 4`

Comment: No no, you misunderstood me. My fault. I meant, why is `1 2 4` there but `1 2 5` is not? My point being that both appear once in your list. So in the list I see 3 patterns: `1 2 3` - twice, `1 2 4` - once, `1 2 5` - once

Comment: @Sotos sorry for the confusion, I have updated my question to define the word _subsequence_ **specifically** to this question, thanks for your comments!